# How would I use Cakepdf within my plugin?

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf

Im tryng to use CakePdf https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf but I need to be able to use it within the plugin I have created. Im not sure `App:uses` to call to use the plugin since im not familiar to his folder structure or what hes importing. I'm using Croogo CMS if that might be of any importance.

**This is what I know and have done:**
 I have read their Read Me tutorial and have followed the intructions to the dot, but again, it does not explain usage within another plugin.
Their `Bootsrap.php` file is as so:

```
App::build(array('Pdf' => array('%s' . 'Pdf' . DS)), App::REGISTER);
App::build(array('Pdf/Engine' => array('%s' . 'Pdf/Engine' . DS)), App::REGISTER);
App::uses('PdfView', 'CakePdf.View');
```

To my understanding this is telling Cakephp to treat the files found within these folders as usable classes within the application. When I try `App:Uses('CakePdf',('CakePdf.Controller')` this does not load the correct class files. I've tested and found that the class is not evein available at my plugin level besided successful plugin bootstraping.

Comment: Not a real answer but a tipp: Croogo is a CMS made by experienced cake-devs and is more or less divided into plugins.. I bet you can find some places where they used dependencies.. https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/master/Plugin/Comments/Controller/CommentsController.php

Comment: have you read [the readme](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf#setup) and tried to use it - if you have please add this to a question, if you have not you need to do that _before_ asking a question. -1 as written for no effort.

Comment: I have read and implemented the readme.

Comment: Im actually using Croogo that is why it is a little difficult implementing in a plugin based CMS. I have asked on their forums.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `App::uses('CakePdf', 'CakePdf.Pdf');`